# Spring Boot 3.1.0 not loads H2 configuration from application-test.properties file correctly in tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have a `Spring Boot 3.1.0` project. I have `application-test.properties` file in `src/test/resources` with data source configured as below:

```
# application-test.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS JSONB AS JSON;
#                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=false
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```

and my test class is:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class UserJpaRepositoryTest {
    // ...
}
```

When I run the test, instead of running `H2` with the configuration in `application-test.properties`, it loads a `H2` database in `DEFAULT` mode:

```
The following 1 profile is active: "test"
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 97 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:46be9e88-3cd6-441f-b9fb-1dd92283945f;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
#                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you see here, it completely ignores `spring.datasource.url` and the configuration I added to databse url is not working and then my tests fail.

What I tried so far without any success:

- Rename `application-test.properties` to `application.properties`
- Move `application-test.properties` to `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

By default, the @DataJpaTest annotation replaces the declared db config and will configure an in-memory embedded database instance with an auto generated unique name. When you want to run tests on real database, use the @AutoConfigureTestDatabase as follows:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class UserJpaRepositoryTest {
    // ...
}
```